# Select multiple columns in data.table by their numeric indices

Tags: r, data.table

How can we select multiple columns using a vector of their numeric indices (position) in `data.table`?

This is how we would do with a `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
df[ , 2:3]
#   b c
# 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 196, accepted):

For versions of **data.table** `>= 1.9.8`, the following all just work:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)

# select single column by index
dt[, 2]
#    b
# 1: 2

# select multiple columns by index
dt[, 2:3]
#    b c
# 1: 2 3

# select single column by name
dt[, "a"]
#    a
# 1: 1

# select multiple columns by name
dt[, c("a", "b")]
#    a b
# 1: 1 2
```

---

For versions of **data.table** `< 1.9.8` (for which numerical column selection required the use of `with = FALSE`), see [this previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13383995/9) of this answer. See also [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.0.md) on  v1.9.8, POTENTIALLY BREAKING CHANGES, point 3.

Comment: No problem. Compare also `dt[,"a"]` and `dt[,"a", with=FALSE]` to see what a helpful option it really is.

Comment: any way to do this without with? for example `DT[,list(b:c)`, as I found it convenient to transform the columns directly in the data table, e.g I can do `DT[,list(1/b,2*c)]`, but this does not work with with.

Comment: You could use .SDcols=2:3 or the character vector of names.  Not sure what you mean regarding example not working with with

Comment: If you are wanting to set by reference DT[, c("b","c") := list(1/b, 2 * c)] should work. See the help for :=

Comment: A change to the package will make `with=FALSE` unnecessary in this case: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1188#issuecomment-127824969

Comment: @Frank -- That's great news! Thanks for bringing it to my attention. Once that change makes its way into the version of **data.table** distributed on CRAN, I'll edit this answer to announce the change up top. (And please -- you or anyone else who reads this -- feel free to ping me with a reminder as soon as that happens.)

Comment: @Frank Is there any version available making unnecessary with=FALSE for the cases explained in your link? Thanks

Comment: @FerranE Not yet. At the top of the linked page, it says "Open" in green, which will switch to "Closed" when it's done. There'll also be a new message towards the bottom of the page. I think it might be a while until this is implemented.

Comment: Is there a data.frame-compatible way?

Comment: @Valentas Funny you should ask. There is not a `data.frame` compatible way to use `with=FALSE`. However, as of about 3 weeks ago, the development version of **data.table** has been modified to calls like `dt[, 2]`, `dt[, 2:3]`, `dt[, "b"]`, and `dt[, c("b", "c")]` behave the same as they do in the with `data.frame`s **without** having to explicitly set `with=FALSE`. It's terrific! [See here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/f78d7901dc5063a5157d37db4831e418ad021fe6) for the particular commit, including the NEWS entry describing the change.

Comment: @Valentas [Here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), in case you need them, are the instructions for how to install the development version. (Do be aware, of course, that the development version, right up there on the bleeding edge, is more likely to have bugs resulting from recent possibly breaking changes to the code base.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien why is dt[, c("b", "c")] not working for me? it gives as output "b" "c".

Comment: @user4050 That syntax only works with the current development version of **data.table**. For all earlier versions, one of which you are almost certainly using, you needed to `dt[, c("b", "c"), with=FALSE]` (as discussed in the main body of the question).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien is there anyway to mix indices and column names?

Answer (score 46):

It's a bit verbose, but i've gotten used to using the hidden `.SD` variable.

```
b<-data.table(a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4)
b[,.SD,.SDcols=c(1:2)]
```

It's a bit of a hassle, but you don't lose out on other data.table features (I don't think), so you should still be able to use other important functions like join tables etc.

Comment: Not a hassle and very useful when creating the column list programmatically

Answer (score 39):

If you want to use column *names* to select the columns, simply use `.()`, which is an alias for `list()`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:2, b = 2:3, c = 3:4)
dt[ , .(b, c)] # select the columns b and c
# Result:
#    b c
# 1: 2 3
# 2: 3 4
```

Answer (score 22):

From v1.10.2 onwards, you can also use `..`

```
dt <- data.table(a=1:2, b=2:3, c=3:4)

keep_cols = c("a", "c")

dt[, ..keep_cols]
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I also found that `dt[, !..keep_cols]` and  `dt[, -..keep_cols]`  works as expected!

Comment: Be aware that `..` is very limited. `cols<-c(1:2); dt[x, ..cols]` succeeds, but `dt[, ..c(1:2)]` fails.

Answer (score 3):

@Tom, thank you very much for pointing out this solution. 
It works great for me.

I was looking for a way to just exclude one column from printing and from the example above. To exclude the second column you can do something like this

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a=1:2, b=2:3, c=3:4)
dt[,.SD,.SDcols=-2]
dt[,.SD,.SDcols=c(1,3)]
```