# Can I programmatically update the type of a set of columns (to factors) in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, r-factor

I would like to modify a set of columns inside a data.table to be factors. If I knew the names of the columns in advance, I think this would be straightforward.

```
library(data.table)
dt1  <- data.table(a = (1:4), b = rep(c('a','b')), c = rep(c(0,1)))
dt1[,class(b)]
dt1[,b:=factor(b)]
dt1[,class(b)]
```

But I don't, and instead have a list of the variable names

```
vars.factors  <- c('b','c')
```

I can apply the factor function to them without a problem ...

```
lapply(vars.factors, function(x) dt1[,class(get(x))])
lapply(vars.factors, function(x) dt1[,factor(get(x))])
lapply(vars.factors, function(x) dt1[,factor(get(x))])
```

But I don't know how to re-assign or update the original column in the data table.

This fails ...

```
  lapply(vars.factors, function(x) dt1[,x:=factor(get(x))])
  # Error in get(x) : invalid first argument
```

As does this ...

```
  lapply(vars.factors, function(x) dt1[,get(x):=factor(get(x))])
  # Error in get(x) : object 'b' not found
```

NB. I tried the answer proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623324/transform-a-set-of-columns-in-a-data-table) without any luck.

Comment: Looking for this? dt2 = as.data.table(lapply(dt1, factor))

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7813578/4241780.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is fairly straightforward:

```
dt1[, (vars.factors) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols=vars.factors]
```

In the `LHS` (of := in `j`), we specify the names of the columns. If a column already exists, it'll be updated, else, a new column will be created. In the RHS, we loop over all the columns in `.SD` (which stands for **S**ubset of **D**ata), and we specify the columns that should be in `.SD` with the `.SDcols` argument.

Following up on comment:

Note that we need to wrap LHS with `()` for it to be *evaluated* and fetch the column names within `vars.factors` variable. This is because we allow the syntax

```
DT[, col := value]
```

when there's only one column to assign, by specifying the column name as a symbol (without quotes), purely for convenience. This creates a column named `col` and assigns `value` to it.

To distinguish these two cases apart, we need the `()`. Wrapping it with `()` is sufficient to identify that we really need to get the values within the variable.

Comment: Thank you - that works. I had tried this `dt1[, vars.factors := lapply(.SD, function(x) factor(x)), .SDcols=vars.factors]` before but it seems to do something very different. Any chance you could explain why?

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation

Answer (score 2):

Using data frame:

```
> df1 = data.frame(dt1)
> df1[,vars.factors] = data.frame(sapply(df1[,vars.factors], factor))
> dt1 = data.table(df1)

> dt1
   a b c
1: 1 1 b
2: 2 2 c
3: 3 3 b
4: 4 4 c

> str(dt1)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: int  1 2 3 4
 $ b: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 4
 $ c: Factor w/ 2 levels "b","c": 1 2 1 2
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: The idea is nice, but this is not the way to do this. There is no need in `data.frame` twice here. You could do the whole thing in one line, such as `dt1[vars.factors] <- lapply(setDF(dt1)[vars.factors], factor) ; setDT(dt1)`

Comment: @ DavidArenburg: Your solution is elegant. I used minimal functions to get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Can also do

```
for (col in vars.factors) 
  set(dt, j=col, value=as.factor(dt1[[col]]))
```

vars.factors may be a vector of integers or character names specifying the columns to modify.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33000778/4241780 for more info.