# Convert data from character to numeric

Tags: r, performance, loops, sapply

I need to convert every value in a data frame from char to numeric.
I wrote:

```
y[,2:ncol(y)]<-sapply(y[,2:ncol(y)], as.numeric)
```

But since the table is big (20000 columns by 3000 rows) takes a lot of time.
Is there a way to do this more efficiently? Thanks

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299159/can-i-programmatically-update-the-type-of-a-set-of-columns-to-factors-in-data

Comment: can you avoid the step that turns all values into factors? `dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` only takes a couple seconds for me without extra overhead. But if you read in as a data frame or coerced a matrix to a data frame, you could probably avoid this step

Comment: You can speed it up even more by avoiding this operation on unnecessary columns with an `if` statement.  `dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.numeric(as.character(x)) else x)`. Or even better would be to only include the factor column in the `lapply` call with `dat[sapply(dat, is.factor)]`

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391921/how-to-convert-entire-dataframe-to-numeric-while-preserving-decimals/26391969#26391969

Comment: @rawr, ok I avoid converting string to factors.... but still have the issue of converting chars to numbers... and it also takes much time. How can I do it faster? Thanks

Comment: @RichardScriven, thanks, but all the columns from 2 to the last need to be converted to numeric. So my main problem is with sapply performance and not with the selection of the rigth cols.

Comment: Have you tried `lapply`?  It's faster

Comment: So you have 20,000 columns and only the first one is not numeric? Sounds like you should really be using a numeric matrix in the first place (see `data.matrix`) and keep that first column in a separate vector, maybe use it as rownames to your matrix if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

With dplyr

if all is defined as character already :

```
y2 <- mutate_all(y, funs(as.numeric))
```

otherwise convert them to characters first

```
y2 <- mutate_all(y, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

(you can overide the dataframe by giving the same name "y" instead of "y2")