# Create automatically new columns in a datatable

Tags: r, data.table

I have a problem with data tables in R.
I have a vector *col_Names* which contains the names of some columns of the datatable *dataset*.

I want to compute the log of the columns in *col_Names* and to substitute the result to the original ones...
If I know the names of these columns and if they are a few, say for example

```
col_Names = c("col1","col2")
```

I could use this code:

```
dataset[,':='(col1=log(col1),col2=log(col2))]
```

but since I don't know the nature of col_Names because it's created by another procedure I can't use that code.

is there any code, I don't know, like

```
dataset[,':='(col_Names=log(col_Names))]
```

which could help me? I don't want to use `for` cycle or `lapply` if it's possible...

Comment: ```dataset[, (col_Names) := lapply(.SD, log), .SDcols = col_Names]```

Comment: There should be a duplicate question for this somewhere.

Comment: David Arenburg...I have specified that I want to do it without lapply if it's possible, thank you anyway!

Comment: Here is a [closely related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623324/transform-a-set-of-columns-in-a-data-table) that uses `lapply`. @FrancescoTamberi `lapply` or some other looping variant is almost certainly necessary.

Comment: `lapply` is the idiomatic way to operate over columns in data.table. What's wrong with it? Running `log` over the whole data set will convert it to matrix first which will be needed to be converted back. Looping over column is much cheaper. Unless you prefer working with matrices instead of data.tables in the first place.

Comment: why so much hatred toward lappy? i know it's sometimes inefficient but in this specific situation, it shouldn't be that bad, unless you have thousands of columns.

Comment: ahah nono I don't hate lapply :) I know how to use it, I'm searching for something, if it exists, which works better for data table...I don't know how many columns will I have, because it's not in mine project, but I want to know if there's an alternative, regarding datatables, for lapply...only for the taste of learn!

Comment: A different option is to use a `for` loop in combination with `set` from data.table

Comment: Your title is misleading. You want to overwrite existing columns, not create new ones... and so the question is essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/16846380/ (setting aside your antipathy towards `lapply`)..?