# R: select range of columns in data.table

Tags: r, select, range, data.table

I am trying to get to grips with the documentation of data.table, but I would like to ask for feedback, where I am going wrong in my reasoning concerning the following.

(1) I would like to select a range of columns from a data.table to create a new data.table.

(2) Also, I would like to just take the first value of each group. With regard to the first question I think the answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383840/select-multiple-columns-in-data-table-r) ,but then with regard to column numbers. But I would like to use column names, which I think is one of the main strengths (and selling points) of data.table.

Here's an example dataset.

```
DT <- data.table(ID=c(101,101,101,102,103,104,104),
                 "year.1" = c(1,5,3,2,3,4,8), 
                 "year.2" = c(4,5,6,NA,1,2,3), 
                 "year.3" = c(1,2,3,7,9,8,0), 
                 "year.4" = c(4,5,NA,1,2,6,9))
setkey(DT,ID)
```

In reality I have much more columns and not just for "year".

```
# ALL OF THESE DONT WORK AND END IN ERRORS
# To extract a range of columns I have tried this:
dt.sub <- DT[,list(year.1:year.3,ID)]
dt.sub <- DT[,c("year.1":"year.3",ID), with=FALSE] # I know shouldn't work since 
# "with=FALSE" is only intended in combination with := according to the documentation
dt.sub <- DT[,lapply(SD),.SDcols= for (i in 1:3) paste0("year.",i) ]
```

For the second question: if I wanted dt.sub to contain only the first observation of each group, I would expect that I could use the "mult" argument. However this also works in a
different way than I anticipate. Using the example on just one column:

```
dt.sub1 <- DT[,year.1, by=ID,mult="first",]
```

This provides no error, but also does not just give the first line of the group. I know that a workaround like:

```
dt.sub1 <- unique(DT[,year.1, by=ID])
```

does provide the expected output, but I feel like I am missing something important with the `mult` option.

Comment: Hi Arun, thank you for your edits, that makes it clearer!

Comment: Since `v1.9.5` this should work: `dt.sub <- DT[,c("year.1":"year.3",ID), with=FALSE]`. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# (1)
DT[, c(paste0('year.', 1:3), 'ID'), with = F]

# (2) 
DT[, year.1[1], by = ID]
```

`mult` is used when *merging/joining* two data.tables and signifies what to do when multiple matches exist. Therefore, as @Arun pointed out, the way to use `mult` for your 2nd question would be (given that you are already keyed by `ID`):

```
DT[J(unique(ID)), list(ID, year.1), mult = 'first']
```