# Select columns by class (e.g. numeric) from a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Why doesn't this work with `data.table`?

It works with `data.frame`. Is there a way to do this with a data table?

```
x <- data.table(v1=1:20,v2=1:20,v3=1:20,v4=letters[1:20])
y <- x[ , sapply(x, is.numeric)]
```

This returns:

```
v1    v2    v3    v4
TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: The data.table FAQ vignette covers this with FAQs 1.1 and 1.2

Comment: Very nearly a duplicate of [select multiple columns in data table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383840/select-multiple-columns-in-data-table-r)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting only numeric columns from a data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863097/selecting-only-numeric-columns-from-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`data.table` needs the `with=FALSE` to grab column numbers.

```
tokeep <- which(sapply(x,is.numeric))
x[ , tokeep, with=FALSE]
```

Comment: Is the which even needed? - `x[,sapply(x,is.numeric),with=FALSE]`

Answer (score 42):

From [`data.table 1.13.0`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1130--24-jul-2020) "`.SDcols` accepts a function which is used to select the columns of `.SD`". Thus, simply `.SDcols = is.numeric`:

```
x[ , .SD, .SDcols = is.numeric]
```

Comment: Hello Hello, I tried.
dt_c[,.SD, .SDcols = sapply(dt_c, as.character)]
 It's not working. 

a solution

Comment: `s/as.character/is.character/`.

Answer (score 3):

You may also try:

```
 x1 <- x[,Filter(is.numeric, .SD)]
 head(x1,3)
 #   v1 v2 v3
#1:  1  1  1
#2:  2  2  2
#3:  3  3  3
```

Although, I have to admit that it is slow for bigger datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @akrun's answer

```
Filter(is.numeric, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write a custom helper called`where()`, and then we can subset a data.frame/data.table `where` `f` is satisfied:

```
where <- function(x, f) {
  colnames(x)[vapply(x, f, logical(1))]
}

df[, where(df, is.numeric), with = FALSE]
```