# R: convert mutate across character call to data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, na

Apologies if I can't find an original post explaining how to do this `tidyverse` to `data.table` conversion.

I would like to `mutate` across all character vectors replacing `<NA>` values in character vectors.

**How can I translate the following text to `data.table`?**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~na_if(.,"")))
```

Comment: Related reading for the general idea: [Apply a function to every specified column in a data.table and update by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/apply-a-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table-and-update-by-referen).

Comment: And how to select `data.table` columns by `class`: [How to select only numeric columns from a data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130531/how-to-select-only-numeric-columns-from-a-data-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(mtcars)[sapply(mtcars, is.character)]
setDT(mtcars)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x == "", NA)), .SDcols = nm1]
```

Comment: Please note that `.SDcols` accepts a function to select the columns. Thus, `.SDcols = is.character` is enough. Cheers