# How to select columns contains a specific character(s) and column type in R data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Suppose that I have a dataframe as shown below;

[image]

Assuming that I wish to select columns that contains "cases" in their column names, and/or if I wish to select numeric columns, how can I achieve this using data.table syntax?

I.e the equivalent of the `tidyverse` code;

```
df <- df |> 
  select(contains("cases"))
```

Or

```
df <- df |> 
  select(where(is.numeric))
```

Resulting to;

[image]

Comment: few options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189979/select-columns-of-data-table-based-on-regex like `library(data.table); cols = grep("cases", names(df), value = TRUE); df[, ..cols]`

Comment: For the second part, base `Filter(is.numeric, df)` or data.table `df[, .SD, .SDcols = is.numeric]`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130531/select-columns-by-class-e-g-numeric-from-a-data-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863097/selecting-only-numeric-columns-from-a-data-frame).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```r
set.seed(42)
quux <- data.table(Region = paste("Region", LETTERS[1:3]), cases_1=runif(3), cases_2=sample(20,size=3), cases_3=runif(3))
quux
#      Region   cases_1 cases_2   cases_3
#      <char>     <num>   <int>     <num>
# 1: Region A 0.9148060      10 0.1346666
# 2: Region B 0.9370754       4 0.6569923
# 3: Region C 0.2861395      18 0.7050648

quux[, .SD, .SDcols = patterns("cases")]
#      cases_1 cases_2   cases_3
#        <num>   <int>     <num>
# 1: 0.9148060      10 0.1346666
# 2: 0.9370754       4 0.6569923
# 3: 0.2861395      18 0.7050648
```

While a literal "if numeric" is as @Tobo said, if your logic is a little more complex then you can use `sapply` to produce a vector (of logical, integer, or names). Note that we can't use `.SD` here.

```r
quux[, .SD, .SDcols = is.numeric]
#      cases_1 cases_2   cases_3
#        <num>   <int>     <num>
# 1: 0.9148060      10 0.1346666
# 2: 0.9370754       4 0.6569923
# 3: 0.2861395      18 0.7050648
quux[, .SD, .SDcols = sapply(quux, is.numeric)] # same output
```

By "more complex", if you want to filter for columns that include "cases" in the name and are numeric but not integer (contrived), then

```r
cols <- grepl("cases", colnames(quux)) & sapply(quux, typeof) == "double"
quux[, .SD, .SDcols = names(which(cols))]
#      cases_1   cases_3
#        <num>     <num>
# 1: 0.9148060 0.1346666
# 2: 0.9370754 0.6569923
# 3: 0.2861395 0.7050648
quux[, names(which(cols)), with=FALSE] # same output
```

(`typeof` returns `double` for numeric and `integer` for integer, a clear differentiation here.)