# R and Rscript give different results for datetime

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript

When I try to execute the following code on RStudio

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

a <- data.frame(c("2017-12-01 00:01:00","2017-12-02 00:01:00"),c(5,6))
colnames(a) <- c("t", "x")
a <- as.data.table(a)
a[, t := parse_date_time(t, orders = "ymd HMS")]
print(class(a$t))
paste("a:", format(a[1,1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

I have the following result:

```
[1] "a: 2017-12-01 00:01:00"
```

But when I try to run the same code under Rscript, the output is

```
[1] "a: 1"
```

Does anyone have the same problem as me? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: R version 3.3.1, platform x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64.

Windows server 2012 version:

Major  Minor  Build  Revision

6      2      9200   0

Comment: For me both gave same output.

Comment: clean/clear your environment if you can and rerun the chunk again

Comment: I already did it, the problem continues. I think I'm going to add more details, such as running it from windows server

Comment: Could you run Sys.getlocale() in both environments and paste the output here?

Comment: In R studio:

 "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"


Rscript output in Powershell:

"LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC
_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"

Comment: Try adding `print(attributes(a$t))`. You may need to specify a timezone and/or Locale in your `parse_date_time` call.

Comment: When I add `print(attributes(a$t))` I get 

$tzone
[1] "UTC"

$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

both in R Studio and Rscript. Specifying a timezone doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: For me, this script makes Rscript auto-load `methods` (with a message). In interactive R, `methods` is one of the always-loaded core packages, but historically it hasn't been loaded by Rscript, so I suspect the auto-loading is a recent-ish change. Try updating R and/or explicitly adding `library(methods)` to your script.

Comment: I tried explicitly calling `library(methods)` and the problem persists. Unfortunately, I can't update R because it may break production code. I got around this bug calling `a[1,t]` instead of `a[1,1]`, which gives me the correct output in both Rstudio and Rscript (so in practical terms the problem is solved). Thanks anyway.

Comment: @LucioCarlosPimentelPaiva can you launch a command window on Windows and show the output of `systeminfo | findstr  /C:"Zone"` please.

Comment: Time Zone:                 (UTC-03:00) Brasilia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is with data.table. In earlier versions of data.table, if we use numeric index, without `with=FALSE`, then it will return the numeric index itself. Hence the output, shared in question. For details on this, one can go through the documentation of `data.table`.

In recent versions of `data.table`, however, this issue has been resolved, and as a result, `data.table` pretty much works like `data.frame`. This is the reason, why no one was able to replicate the output shared in the question.

Below is the updated code, using `with=FALSE` option with data.table.

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

a <- data.frame(c("2017-12-01 00:01:00","2017-12-02 00:01:00"),c(5,6), stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # stringsAsFactors=TRUE
colnames(a) <- c("t", "x")
a$t1 <- parse_date_time(a$t, orders = "ymd HMS")
a <- as.data.table(a)
a[, t := parse_date_time(as.character(t), orders = "ymd HMS")]
print(class(a$t))
paste("a:", format(a[1,1, with=FALSE], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

You can get info on package version using using `sessionInfo()`. Using the package versions, the issue can be identified.

Comment: The problem persists. The version of `data.table` and `lubridate` that I'm using are 

`data.table_1.9.6 lubridate_1.6.0`

Comment: On second thought, the issue could be with data.table. Hence adding with=FALSE in data.table. Hope this resolves your problem. See link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383840/select-multiple-columns-in-data-table-by-their-numeric-indices.

Comment: Using `with=FALSE` works like a charm! Thank you very much. Please update your answer.

Comment: Updated my answer. @Lucio Carlos Pimentel Paiva You are most welcome.