# Select columns using a variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Given a data.table, how can I select a set of columns using a variable?

Example:

```
df[, 1:3]
```

is OK, but

```
idx <- 1:3
df[, idx]
```

is not OK: column named "idx" does not exist.

How can I use idx to select the columns in the simplest possible way?

Comment: Your indexing works well for `iris[, idx]`

Comment: Are you sure you have run ```idx <- 1:3``` first? It should work.

Comment: Error in `[.data.table`(df, , idx) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'idx' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..idx]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Comment: Now I read... why should I use the double dot?

Comment: If it is data.table. you need `df[, ..idx]` or `df[, idx, with = FALSE]`

Comment: [Extract columns from data table by numeric indices stored in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227360/extract-columns-from-data-table-by-numeric-indices-stored-in-a-vector); [Select / assign to data.table when variable names are stored in a character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-when-variable-names-are-stored-in-a-character-vect). From `?data.table`: `colNum = 2` "to refer vars in `j` from the outside of data use `..` prefix"; `DT[, ..colNum]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `..` before the idx to select the columns in `data.table` or `with = FALSE`

```
library(data.table)
df[, ..idx]
df[, idx, with = FALSE]
```

Comment: You know of any such function support natively by R?

Comment: @user1535147 if you are using `base R`, then df[idx] would work where `df` is a data.frame