# Subset a data.table based on column value where column is selected based on sequence

Tags: r, data.table

Let say I have below `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x=sample(letters, 1e6, TRUE), y=rnorm(1e6), v=runif(1e6))
```

Now I want to subset `DT` based on the 1st column value equals to `letters[1:2]`

If the *chose column by name*, then this is straighforward -

```
DT[x %in% letters[1:2]]
```

However I want to *select column by placement* i.e. first column or 4th column etc

**Below code doesnt work**

```
DT[1 %in% letters[1:2]]
```

Any pointer on what will be right syntax to select column based on placement, would be helpful

Comment: Related: [Select multiple columns in data.table by their numeric indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383840/select-multiple-columns-in-data-table-by-their-numeric-indices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
DT[DT[[1]] %in% letters[1:2]]
```

Comment: you might want to use `%chin%` for character data type